# Modifying resolv.conf when when bringing network interface up on system startup

Tags: linux, networking, startup

My Linux box currently has a network interface that allows me to connect to a network on a different subnet. I've achieved this by modifying the routing table when the network interface is brought up. The 'remote' network also has a DNS server so I want to add that to my /etc/resolv.conf file when the interface enabled.

My `/etc/network/interfaces` file currently has the following:

```
# Secondary network interface (using NAT)
allow-hotplug eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
        post-up route add -net 172.16.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.0.3.2
        post-up echo 'Up and running...' >> /home/sysadmin/net-result.txt; date >> /home/sysadmin/net-result.txt
        post-up sed -i '1inameserver 172.16.0.1' /etc/resolv.conf
        post-down sed -i '/^nameserver 172.16.0.1/d' /etc/resolv.conf
```

(The line `post-up echo...` is just there to prove that the commands are being run and that they have access to the file system.)

This works fine when I use `ifup eth1` and `ifdown eth1` from the command line to control the interface. The line `nameserver 172.16.0.1` appears (and disappears) in `/etc/resolv.conf` as expected.

However, it's not working on system startup for some reason. The `route` command *is* being executed (because I can see the modifications in the routing table) and the `/home/sysadmin/net-status.txt` file is also being modified as expected, but `/etc/resolv.conf` does not change.

I can't work out what the problem is. Does anyone have any suggestions?

(The Linux box is actually a virtual machine, and the remote network is accessed via a VPN, but I don't think either of these details really have a bearing on the problem in this context.)

Comment: I think you can try redirecting the stdout & stderr of that command to redirect to some file to know why the resolv.conf is not getting updated on bootup.

Comment: @pradeepchhetri - I appended `&> /home/sysadmin/net-up-result.txt` to the `post-up sed...` stanza. The file time-stamp changes (so it's being modified) but the contents are empty.

Comment: Is the Linux box an ubuntu machine?  The latest versions of *buntu generate resolv.conf out of thin air by default based on whatever network events they deem relevant.